# Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic: white background for systray icons

Tags: gnome-classic, system-tray

All systray icons (not indicators) are with white background.

[image: white background sample]

How can I change it to panel's color?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain this "changing from Xinerama to TwinView". I have the same problem you had but find no way to solve it. Please help!

Comment: I have 2 monitor configuration on Nvidia card, and I changed multimonitor settings in  nvidia-settings tool from Xinerama to TwinView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved: switched from Xinerama to TwinView